# How to input vector members in the console while using a while loop?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm stuck trying to input all vector members into the console.
All members should be odd, and if the the vector size is equal to 10, the program has to stop with further inputs (which it does). Should I use a for loop instead of the while loop?
Wherever I put `cout << input << endl`, it either messes with the loop or just displays the last vector member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> x;
    int input;

    cout << "Enter vector members." << endl;

    while(cin >> input)
    {
        if (input % 2 != 0)
        {
            x.push_back(input);
        }
        
        if (x.size() == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        cout << input << endl; // fail
    }
    
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is not part of the `vector`. It's a value that you may or may not have placed into the `vector`. If you want to print the contents of `x`, you have to print the contents of `x`. When you exit the loop and `x` is filled up, use a `for` loop to iterate through `x`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> x;
    int input;

    cout << "Enter vector members." << endl;

    while(cin >> input)
    {
        if (input % 2 != 0)
        {
            x.push_back(input);
        }

        if (x.size() == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // loop over x and print
    for (int val:x) 
    {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
}
```